# How to use a image created by UIImage category

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have created a method to create a circle which is working fine when i am using this method in the same class but when i making a category of this doesnot show up

```
#import "UIImage+circle.h"
@implementation UIImage (circle)    
- (UIImage * ) makeImageofColor:(UIColor *)color
 {
        UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                                bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(15, 15));
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
        [circle fill];
        UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return bezierImage;
    }
   @end
```

and in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UIImage *img;
      self.ImageView1.image=[img makeImageofColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reference problem,Simply replace instance method declaration

```
- (UIImage * ) makeImageofColor:(UIColor *)color
```

with class method declaration

```
+ (UIImage * ) makeImageofColor:(UIColor *)color
```

and call

```
self.ImageView1.image=[UIImage makeImageofColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "UIImage+circle.h" file declare your category method like this

```
- (UIImage * ) makeImageofColor:(UIColor *)color;
```

and import  "**UIImage+circle.h**" in "**ViewController.m**"

This will solve your problem.

Comment: did you declare category method in .h file?